# AWS ElasticSearch request timeout in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticache

When I go the Elastic search in AWS console and click on my domain there is error loading data.

[image: error]

```
/_stats: {"code":"ProxyRequestServiceException","message":"Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)"}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be one of the following:  the cluster is not available, the status of the domain is not active, the cluster might be too loads, there are too many indices/shards/too large mapping.

I would start by checking the status of the cluster, and try to use the rest API directly, you can start `_cluster/health`, check the indices list using `_cat/indices` , and get the indices mappings in order to check where the issue is.